# How to highlight tree nodes

Tags: java, javascript, jsf-1.2

I am displaying two trees using Rich faces 3.3.2 and JSF 1.2 and now I have a requirement to compare two trees and highlight their difference.

Example:
Consider two trees one on the left and other on the right...
Suppose I have a node under left tree but it is not there on the right tree then i have to highlight the node and also its child node present in the left tree.

Answer (score 0):

while building the trees i would create in the same moment for each tree a hashmap where you can add the node while adding them to the tree. in the end you only have to compare the difference from the two maps and highlight the node positions.